# Wie kann man die Konstruktion "es lebt sich gut" erklären?

Tags: etymology, phrase, reflexive

Wie funktionieren die folgenden Konstruktionen?

```
In dieser Stadt lebt es sich gut. 
In diesem Bett schläft es sich herrlich. 
Auf diesem Stuhl sitzt es sich gemütlich.
```

Ich weiß, dass man auch "*hier lässt es sich gut leben*" sagen kann, ich suche aber nach einer Erklärung bzgl. der Konstruktion ohne "lassen".

Comment: Ich habe dies "es ... sich ..." Wortwahl als eine etwas archaische Betonung verstanden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beim reflexiven Verb sind Subjekt und Objekt identisch:

> Ich wasche mich.

*Es* dient als formales Subjekt zur Bezeichnung unpersönlicher Vorgänge ([Bedeutung II.1.e](https://www.dwds.de/wb/es#d-1-2-1)):

> Ich ... mich. (persönlicher Vorgang ⇒ bestimmtes oder Definitpronomen)
> Es ... sich. (unpersönlicher Vorgang ⇒ Indefinitpronomen)

Die reflexive Konstruktion mit *es ... sich* kann immer durch eine nicht-reflexive Version mit *man* ausgedrückt werden:

> In dieser Stadt lebt es sich gut. = Man lebt gut in dieser Stadt.

Comment: Bitte erklären Sie den letzten Teil genauer. Sagen Sie, dass "man" immer durch "es sich" ersetzt werden kann? "Es muss sich Steuern zahlen", statt "Man muss Steuern zahlen", zum Beispeil?

Comment: @RDBury Ich wollte damit nur die Konstruktion erklären, nach der du gefragt hast. Man kann jede von ihnen durch eine nicht-reflexive Variante mit *man* ersetzten: "In diesem Bett schläft man herrlich." "Auf diesem Stuhl sitzt man gemütlich." Umgekehrt kann man aber nicht immer ein *man* durch *es ... sich* ersetzen. Ich habe meine Antwort überarbeitet, um das klarer zu machen.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Der DWDS-Eintrag sagt, dass das "es sich" in "es+<Verb>+"sich "+<Modalbestimmung> verwendet wird. Die Bedeutung von "Modalbestimmung" ist mir noch nicht ganz klar. Ich nehme an, es ist wie ein Modaladverb oder "wie adverb".

Comment: Diese Antwort fehlt historischer Beleg, isso